# Action Filter to Display Conditional Simple Message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to implement a very simple feature for my homework.
The feature is that something you could call a system lock,
So, this lock status (Lock or Unlocked etc) is stored in sql server database.
So if the system is locked for example, i would then put the desired message in bootstrap alert and display it in the shared layout by using session.
Here is my action Filter Code

```
public class DisplayLockAlert : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    MasterLockMgr lockMgr = new MasterLockMgr(new MvcFertilizerEntities(), Membership.GetUser());

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        switch (lockMgr.GetMasterLockStatus())
        {
            case Status.Locked:
                filterContext.HttpContext.Session.Add(AlertMessages.Key_Locked, AlertMessages.System_Locked);
                break;
            default:
                filterContext.HttpContext.Session.Remove(AlertMessages.Key_Locked);
                break;
        }
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

here is the code to retrieve the Lock status

```
public string GetMasterLockStatus()
    {
        return db.Master_Lock.OrderBy(l => l.ID).FirstOrDefault().Lock_Status;
    }
```

However, for some reason, something strange happened,
the switch case always return same result despite i have changed the lock status in the data base. I have tried to change it from OnActionExecuting to OnResultExecuting and even try to use if/else instead but nothing solves it

And it would only be correct when i stop debugging and re start the debugging again.

Any idea on better approach or the problem solving is welcomed.

Comment: Is there more than one record in the `Master_Lock` table? Are you updating the right one?

Comment: nope, it's only 1 record, i made it fixed like that, i have tried to put breakpoints too and the method is returning correct result

Answer (score 0):

This might sound a bit clumsy but, i tried to move the lockMgr varible to above the switch statement and it just fixed it...

```
public class DisplayLockAlert : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        MasterLockMgr lockMgr = new MasterLockMgr(new MvcFertilizerEntities(), Membership.GetUser());
        switch (lockMgr.GetMasterLockStatus())
        {
            case Status.Locked:
                filterContext.HttpContext.Session.Add(AlertMessages.Key_Locked, AlertMessages.System_Locked);
                break;
            default:
                filterContext.HttpContext.Session.Remove(AlertMessages.Key_Locked);
                break;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```